Class of compact sets is compact class
Class $\mathfrak{K}$ of subsets of X is compact class if for every countable $\{K_n\}$, $K_n \in \mathfrak{K}$, next conditions are equivalent:
\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n=\emptyset \iff \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \bigcap_{n=1}^{N}K_n=\emptyset
\end{align*}
So, it is easy to show that class $\mathfrak{K}$ of compact sets of some topological space X is compact class if compact sets are closed ($X\setminus {K_i}$ is an open covering of $K_1$). So, it is true for Hausdorff spaces.
Question: is it true for non-Hausdorff spaces? If yes, how to prove, if no, is there any easy counter-examples?

Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...\}$ be a countably infinite set, and suppose the topology on $X$ has only finitely many open sets.

It follows that all subsets of $X$ are compact.

Let $K_1,K_2,K_3,...$ be given by $K_n=\{x_i{\,|\,}i\ge n\}$.

Then we have
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n={\large{\varnothing}}
$$
but for all positive integers $N$ we have
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{N}K_n=K_N\ne{\large{\varnothing}}
$$
hence the class of compact subsets of $X$ is not a compact class.
